# Interesting Combinatorics question relating the coefficients of variables in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics

I tried this problem for a while by canceling the factorials on either side but for whatever reason, wasn't able to solve it.
Could someone please help me?

Is there a proof that $\binom{a}{b}<\binom{a+1}{b-1}$?
If there is, explain.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a \ge b \ge 1$, $${a \choose b}/{a+1 \choose b-1} = \dfrac{(a-b+1)(a-b+2)}{(a+1)b}$$
What happens when $b$ is small (e.g.  $1$) and $a$ is large?

Comment: This is exactly where I left off. When a is large and b is small, then doesn't it imply that the fraction is large, which is contrary to what we wanted to prove?

Comment: @dREaM - What next? I have the same result. How do I prove anything from that?

Comment: @dREaM - Yeah, I did.

Comment: But isn't it 3a instead of 2a?

Comment: What's the question?  You can't prove something that isn't true.

Comment: Why isn't it true?

Comment: Because if $b$ is small and $a$ is large, ${a \choose b} > {a+1 \choose b-1}$.

Comment: Why is that always true? For example, with a = 3 and b = 2, ${3 \choose 2} > {4 \choose 1}$ is wrong. Could you please define large and small?

Comment: If $b \ge 1$, it suffices to have $a \ge 3 b$.